# How do I determine the coordinates of an item within a stackpanel?

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I have a `StackPanel` that has N-number of children. I want to get the x,y coordinates of the children relative to the parent `StackPanel`.

The children in the `StackPanel` are centered horizontally so whenever the `StackPanel` resizes the children are centered. Here's what I'm doing to get the TopLeft corner of the child item relative to the `StackPanel`:

```
Dim parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(childItem)
childItem.TranslatePoint(VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(childItem).TopLeft, parent)
```

Let's say in the initial layout the point it gives me back is (20,0). Now the layout changes and the `StackPanel` widens, but the children remain centered. I would expect this method now to give me something back like (150, 0) but it's still giving me (20,0). Visually I can see the items are in the center of the `StackPanel`, but it's still giving me the initial coordinates. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass new Point(0,0) to the TranslatePoint function.  Since the child is translating a point in its coordinate space to another visual, its upper left corner is (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing because I don't know what FindAncestors.FindAncestor does, but I'm guessing it returns the *container* of the item rather than horizontally-centered *content* of the container. You want the top-left coordinate of the content, not the container.

Comment: I changed the code to make it more undstandable (I hope). I'm getting the parent container and then translating the bounds of the child to it's parent